# How to copy a row from DataTables and add to this table? (including renaming name-attribute)

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a asp.mvc4-project with a DataTables-jquery plugin. I want to add a new row (by making a copy of the first row).

I'm using the function `fnAddData` with this code:

```
$('#processedresultlines .add-row').on('click', function (e) {
  $('#processedresultlines').dataTable().fnAddData
  (
      ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
  );
});
```

and using `fnCreatedRow` for fill in the correct html:

```
"fnCreatedRow": function (nRow, aData, iDataIndex) {

     var rowdata = oTable.fnGetData(0);  //get first row-data
     for (var i = 1; i < rowdata.length; i++) {
         var newValue = rowdata[i];
       $('td:eq(' + i + ')', nRow).html($(newValue));
     }
```

In this example, the variable `newValue` has the next content:

```
"<select class="width100" id="processResultLine_Ledger" name="processResultLine.Ledger">
<option value="">---</option> 
<option value="0090">0090 </option>
<option value="9060">9060 </option>
</select>"
```

This works, but also with the same name-attributes (and ID-attribute)

**How can I change this name-attribute / id-attribute?**